# Script not working with new versions of jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my script run very good with jquery 1.2.4 but i don't want use 2 different version of jquery so how can i resolve my problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#username").change(function() { 
    var usr = $("#username").val();

    if(usr.length >= 3)
    {
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "check.php",  
        data: "username="+ usr,  
        success: function(msg) {  
          alert(msg);

          $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 
            if(msg == 'OK')
            { 
              $("#username").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
              $("#username").addClass("object_ok");
              $(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="accepted.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
            }
            else  
            {  
              $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
              $("#username").addClass("object_error");
              $(this).html(msg);
            }
          });
        } 
      }); 
    }
    else
    {
      $("#status").html('<font color="red">The username should have at least <strong>3</strong> characters.</font>');
      $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
      $("#username").addClass("object_error");
    }
  });
});
```

When i add a new jquery version my alert(msg) return the value of my php echo so i modified a litle bit my php code and now i get the correct msg value but my text won't display

```
    $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
    $("#username").addClass("object_error");
    $(this).html(msg);
```

same result if i add

```
<label id="errorusername" class="rederror">
document.getElementById('errorusername').innerHTML="Username ne doit pas etre vide";
```

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/): **As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document**. It makes no sense to listen to those events on anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will change  `$("#status").ajaxComplete` to  `$(document).ajaxComplete`, and I think you will change `$(this).html(msg);` to `$('#status').html(msg);` also.

Comment: the if and the else is not recognized even if msg == ok but thanks anyway i'll take note for future use

Comment: It is because $("#status").ajaxComplete not working, change it with $(document).ajaxComplete

Comment: i tryed but when i try the page stuck on my php form

Comment: is it alerted? alert(msg);

Comment: @MartinDubois 1 more thing: Bring the creation of the `ajaxComplete` event handler outside your `$.ajax()` call. You're creating duplicate event handlers every time you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just simply use something like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="errorMsg" value="Put your error messages from php here">
```

and then call it from Jquery

```
var errormsg = $("#errorMsg").val;
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The questioner is attempting to retrieve data in an asynchronous context.

Answer (score 0):

Add the latest version of jquery and migrate plugin of jquery. These will work for you ..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: this answer work but if i can avoid using another version i'll be happy.

with the old version my php script echo directly into my label, with the new version my php echo in msg variable